# How to access localhost application using selenium grid and docker

Tags: docker, selenium

As per my project requirement, i need to build the application locally and i need to run my suite locally.

I setup Selenium Hub on 4444 port and connected the node, so my Hub and Node are connected.

Below code is to route execution through grid:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
getDriver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", cap);
```

But when i try to access my local application with any of the following url, i am getting errors:
when i access my application with url "**http://localhost:4200/admin/login**" or "**[http://127.0.0.1:4200/admin/login**"](http://127.0.0.1:4200/admin/login**%22) I am getting this error "**(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**"

When i use "**[http://host.docker.internal:4200/admin/login**"](http://host.docker.internal:4200/admin/login**%22), i think it is not internally able to link and unable to find any element.

I am able to run any internet applications without any issues.

I am using Docker for desktop 2.0.0.3 in MAC.

Comment: Can you share the docker-compose file code? how are you trying to link them?